# Reader Writer program in C using mutexes and pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex

I am stuck on a Reader/Writer problem in C. Can anybody explain me what is happening in the code below.  I dont understand how the execution flows after the pthread_create(&tid,NULL,writer,NULL) line.

```
#include<pthread.h>
//#include<semaphore.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

pthread_mutex_t x,wsem;
pthread_t tid;
int readcount;

void intialize()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&x,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&wsem,NULL);
    readcount=0;
}

void * reader (void * param)
{
    int waittime;
    waittime = rand() % 5;
    printf("\nReader is trying to enter");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&x);
    readcount++;
    if(readcount==1)
        pthread_mutex_lock(&wsem);
    printf("\n%d Reader is inside ",readcount);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&x);
    sleep(waittime);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&x);
    readcount--;
    if(readcount==0)
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&wsem);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&x);
    printf("\nReader is Leaving");
}   

void * writer (void * param)
{
    int waittime;
    waittime=rand() % 3;
    printf("\nWriter is trying to enter");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&wsem);
    printf("\nWrite has entered");
    sleep(waittime);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&wsem);    
    printf("\nWriter is leaving");
    sleep(30);
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    int n1,n2,i;    
    printf("\nEnter the no of readers: ");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    printf("\nEnter the no of writers: ");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        pthread_create(&tid,NULL,reader,NULL);  
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
        pthread_create(&tid,NULL,writer,NULL);
    sleep(30);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You don't call your `initialize()` function to initialise your mutexes.

Comment: Within `main()`, you do not call the function `initialize()`. This is the function that initialises your two mutexes `x` and `wsem`.

Comment: You need to first understand what a reader/writer problem is, then jump to the code.

Comment: @DaV sorry i forgot to call initialize() within the main(). i dont have any problem in executing the above code can you explain me what is happening after sleep() i am concerned with the execution flow after sleep statement in the reader function please help

Comment: @brokenfoot i know what reader writer problem is but I don't know how to write C code for reader writer using semaphore and pthread so it would be really helpful for me if you explain me the concept of thread and explain me what the execution flow of the above code will be after sleep statement in the reader function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you havn't get your answer then you can try following code. Try to compare with above given code.

```
semaphore mutex = 1;                 // Controls access to the reader count
semaphore db = 1;                    // Controls access to the database
int reader_count;                    // The number of reading processes accessing the data

Reader()
{
  while (TRUE) {                     // loop forever
     down(&mutex);                          // gain access to reader_count
     reader_count = reader_count + 1;       // increment the reader_count
     if (reader_count == 1)
         down(&db);                         // if this is the first process to read the database,
                                            // a down on db is executed to prevent access to the 
                                            // database by a writing process
     up(&mutex);                            // allow other processes to access reader_count
     read_db();                             // read the database
     down(&mutex);                          // gain access to reader_count
     reader_count = reader_count - 1;       // decrement reader_count
     if (reader_count == 0)
         up(&db);                           // if there are no more processes reading from the 
                                            // database, allow writing process to access the data
     up(&mutex);                            // allow other processes to access reader_countuse_data();
                                            // use the data read from the database (non-critical)
}

Writer()
{
  while (TRUE) {                     // loop forever
     create_data();                         // create data to enter into database (non-critical)
     down(&db);                             // gain access to the database
     write_db();                            // write information to the database
     up(&db);                               // release exclusive access to the database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nice question try to use this. It seems like u r confused with reader writer problem.

```
void reader(){
   while(1){
      wait(x);
        readcount++;
        if (readcount==1) 
             wait(wsem);
      signal(x);
      doReading();
      wait(x);
        readcount--;
        if (readcount==0)
             signal(wsem);
      signal(x);
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually the code which i pasted above is working. Can you tell me how the execution flows after pthread_create(&tid,NULL,writer,NULL) line in the code. I am getting(at the output) "Reader's leaving" line after "Writer is trying to enter" how this is happening....

Comment: Why can't you just give the OP an answer to his problem?  I don't think code dumps were requested here.