# Reader/Writer problem in C using pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex

I am learning pthreads when I came across the reader/writer problem in C. The problem is very simple where the "writer" threads will be accessing data from an external source and the "reader" threads will be reading this data from the shared buffer and then pseudo processing the data. The reader and writer threads need to run continuously in a while loop.

I am trying to implement and compile this on a standard unix system with a POSIX interface.

I have looked through some of the stack overflow questions:

[Reader Writer program in C using mutexes and pthreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23094813/reader-writer-program-in-c-using-mutexes-and-pthreads)

[reader/writer lock in pthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482648/reader-writer-lock-in-pthread)

and I have gotten no where with these.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 50
#define M 10
#define N 20

int get_external_data(char *buffer, int bufferSizeInBytes);
void process_data(char *buffer, int bufferSizeInBytes);

int get_external_data(char *buffer, int bufferSizeInBytes){
    int status;
    int val;
    char srcString[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    val = (int)(rand() % 62);
    if (bufferSizeInBytes < val){
        return (-1);
    }

    strncpy(buffer, srcString, val);
    return val;
}

void process_data(char *buffer, int bufferSizeInBytes){
    int i;
    if(buffer) {
        printf("thread %li - ", pthread_self());

        for(i = 0; i < bufferSizeInBytes; i++) {
            printf("%c", buffer[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
        memset(buffer, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);
    } else {
        printf("error in process data - %li\n", pthread_self());
    }

    return;
}


pthread_mutex_t data_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t print_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
sem_t data_count;

typedef struct node {
    struct node *next;
    char *data;
    int length;
} node_t;

node_t *head, *tail;

/**
 * This thread is responsible for pulling data off of the shared data 
 * area and processing it using the process_data() API.
 */

void *reader_thread(void *arg) {
    int rc;
    node_t *removed_node;

    while(1) {
        rc = sem_wait(&data_count);
        if (0 != rc) {
            return NULL;
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&data_lock);

        assert(NULL != head);
        removed_node = head;
        head = head->next;

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&data_lock);

        //Adding this lock for sake of readability at the cost of reduced consumption rate...will run out of memory eventually.

        pthread_mutex_lock(&print_lock);

        process_data(removed_node->data, removed_node->length);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_lock);

        free(removed_node->data);
        free(removed_node);
    }

    return NULL;
}


/**
 * This thread is responsible for pulling data from a device using
 * the get_external_data() API and placing it into a shared area
 * for later processing by one of the reader threads.
 */

void *writer_thread(void *arg) {
    int length;
    char *buffer;
    node_t *new_node;

    new_node = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*buffer) * BUFF_SIZE);

    while(1) {

        length = get_external_data(buffer, BUFF_SIZE);

        if (length == -1) {
            //data too big, discard it and try again;
            continue;
        }

        new_node->next = NULL;
        new_node->length = length;
        new_node->data = buffer;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&data_lock);


        if (head == NULL) { //The linked list is completely empty   
            head = new_node;
            tail = new_node;        
        } else { //There are items in the list and we're appending  
            tail->next = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&data_lock);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&print_lock);

        printf("thread %ld wrote - %s \n", pthread_self(), buffer);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_lock);

        sem_post(&data_count);

        buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(*buffer) * BUFF_SIZE);
        new_node = (node_t*) malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = sem_init(&data_count, 0, 0);
    pthread_t dummy; //creating a dummy thread

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        pthread_create(&dummy, NULL, reader_thread, NULL);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) { 
        pthread_create(&dummy, NULL, writer_thread, NULL);
    }

    sleep(100);
    return 0;   
}
```

The thread synchronization is there without any compilation errors but my program stops after the writer thread writes on a buffer a few times.

The reader and writer threads need to run continuously in a while loop, but they don’t in my case.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: gcc .... -lpthread.

Comment: Well, you have a return with no value in a function that returns `void *`. return something,.

Comment: you'll may also need -lrt  for sem_* functions - depending on the platform

Comment: Your program does not stop, because it never *starts*.  Your build is failing with some compiler warnings and link errors.

Answer (score 1):

With *gcc* add the option `-lpthread` to link with the *pthread* library, I also encourage you to add the options `-pedantic -Wextra -Wall`

There are several problems in your program, some are indicated by the compiler

In :

> ```
> printf("thread %i - ", pthread_self());
> printf("error in process data - %i\n", pthread_self());
> ```

In the POSIX standard it is not required that `pthread_t` is an arithmetic type, so it can be a struct etc and you cannot write it as an *int*. May be in your case it is an *int* (more probably an `unsigned long`) but this is not portable, and it is better to manage by yourself an identifier associated to each thread.

In `reader_thread` :

> ```
> return;
> ```

but the function return a `void*`, replace it by `return NULL;` for instance

In `writer_thread` :

> ```
> printf("thread %d wrote - %s", buffer);
> ```

has three problems:

- an argument of type *int* is missing (probably you wanted `pthread_self()`)
- *buffer* is set by `get_external_data` using `strncpy`, so the null ending character is *not* present but required by *printf %s* (when the missing argument will be added or *%d* removed)
- *buffer* can be freed by `reader_thread`, probably you supposed it is protected by the semaphore but this is not the case

In `get_external_data` *status* is unused

In *main*

> ```
>  usleep(100);
> ```

is a very short time given to the threads to work, and in fact you just want to be blocked, so you can replace it by `pthread_join(dummy, NULL);`

---

A proposal to have thread identifiers : allocate an *int* in the heap, set it with a unique number and give it in parameter to the created threads :

```
int main() {
    ...
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
      int * m = malloc(sizeof(int));

      *m = i;
      pthread_create(&dummy, NULL, reader_thread, m);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < M; i++) { 
      int * m = malloc(sizeof(int));

      *m = 100 + i;
      pthread_create(&dummy, NULL, writer_thread, m);
    }
    ...
}
```

and

```
void *writer_thread(void *arg) {
    int id = *((int*) arg);
    ...
    free((int*) arg);
    ...
    printf("thread %d wrote - %s", id, buffer);
    ...
}
```

and

```
void *reader_thread(void *arg) {
    int id = *((int*) arg);
    ...
    free((int*) arg);
    ...
    process_data(removed_node->data, removed_node->length, id);
    ...
}
```

and

```
void process_data(char *buffer, int bufferSizeInBytes, int id){
    ...
        printf("thread %i - ", id);
...
        printf("error in process data - %i\n", id);
...
}
```

---

After the previous changes an execution under *valgrind* with errors dues to the other problems :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra -Wall t.c -lpthread
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==3847== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3847== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3847== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3847== Command: ./a.out
==3847== 
==3847== Thread 22:
==3847== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3847==    at 0x484B20C: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x48FD68F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847== 
thread 100 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEthread 103 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxthread 1 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDE
thread 0 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyx
thread 102 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABthread 103 wrote - 0123456thread 2 - 012
thread 101 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghithread 105 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFGHIJKLMthread 3 - 0123456
thread 109 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxAthread 3 - 0123456789abcdefghi
==3847== Invalid read of size 1
==3847==    at 0x484B1EC: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x48FD68F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847==  Address 0x49fcd18 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 50 free'd
==3847==    at 0x4848B8C: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==3847==  Block was alloc'd at
==3847==    at 0x4847568: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==3847== 
thread 107 wrote - 0123456789abcdefgthread 100 wrote - thread 100 wrote - 0123456789athread 101 wrote - 0123456789abcthread 7 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFGHIJKLM
thread 7 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxAB
thread 9 - 0123456789abc
thread 9 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxA
thread 108 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABthread 105 wrote - 01thread 8 - 0123456789ab
thread 108 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghithread 12 - 0123
thread 103 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFGthread 101 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvthread 103 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFGthread 101 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvthread 14 - 0123456789a
thread 101 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklthread 101 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxthread 101 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFGHthread 101 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqthread 101 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuthread 101 wrote - 0123thread 102 wrote - thread 2 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
thread 2 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqr
thread 2 - 0123456789abcdefghi
thread 2 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFG
thread 100 wrote - 0123456789abcthread 100 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFGHIJKthread 4 - 0123456789abcdefghijkl
thread 109 wrote - thread 13 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxAB
thread 108 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFGHIthread 19 - 0123456789abc
thread 101 wrote - 0thread 18 - 01
thread 108 wrote - 0123456thread 108 wrote - 01thread 108 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijthread 10 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopq
thread 8 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
==3847== Thread 30:
==3847== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3847==    at 0x484B1F4: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x48FD68F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847== 
==3847== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3847==    at 0x48FBEEC: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847== 
==3847== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3847==    at 0x48FBF0C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847== 
==3847== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3847==    at 0x49245B8: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.4 (fileops.c:1294)
==3847==    by 0x48FBF7B: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847== 
==3847== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3847==    at 0x48FBF80: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847== 
==3847== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3847==    at 0x48FBF90: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1637)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847== 
==3847== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3847==    at 0x48FBE24: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1668)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847== 
==3847== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3847==    at 0x48FBE6C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1668)
==3847==    by 0x4902ADF: printf (printf.c:33)
==3847==    by 0x10B83: writer_thread (t.c:144)
==3847==    by 0x4898FC3: start_thread (pthread_create.c:458)
==3847==    by 0x498D037: ??? (clone.S:76)
==3847== 
thread 108 wrote - thread 108 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijkthread 12 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDEFGHIJKL
thread 108 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijthread 106 wrote - thread 5 - 0123456789abcdefg
thread 106 wrote - thread 106 wrote - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxABCDthread 16 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx
thread 16 - 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
==3847== 
==3847== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3847==     in use at exit: 5,444 bytes in 74 blocks
==3847==   total heap usage: 155 allocs, 81 frees, 8,138 bytes allocated
==3847== 
==3847== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3847==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3847==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3847==      possibly lost: 4,080 bytes in 30 blocks
==3847==    still reachable: 1,364 bytes in 44 blocks
==3847==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3847== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3847== 
==3847== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3847== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3847== ERROR SUMMARY: 51 errors from 10 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! 
It somewhat solved the issue.

I updated my code with the issue I was having.

You were right about the: 

    `usleep(100)`

I changed it to 

   `sleep(100)`

and it is working fine.

But could you check the code I just edited, just to be sure if it is fine now?

Comment: @arsalunic612 your new version of the code does not solve all the problems, I edited my answer with an execution under _valgrind_ where you can see a lot of random errors (depends on the thread concurrency)

Comment: I will try to work on your proposed solution to have thread identifiers. I will let you know if it takes me anywhere.

Comment: Many ports of GCC need `-pthread` (which implies `-lpthread`), but sets additional compiler switches, defines, whatever necessary for a multi(p)threaded application to work properly.